Use of MERGE reserved keyword in different versions of SQL Server
I am getting runtime error while calling a stored procedure (as shown below) in SQL Server 2012 but not in SQL Server 2014, it looks very fundamental, but I would like to know exact reason and if there is any work around.
It runs just fine in SQL Server 2012 against a database with compatibility 90:
SP_AddState 29,merge

But it causes an error in SQL Server 2014:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'merge'.

It works only when called as
SP_AddState 29,'merge'

What is the reason of this execution behavior?

MERGE is a reserved keyword. Though, I'm pretty sure it was reserved before SQL Server 2014.

Merge is a keyword in later versions due to MERGE statement, so you can't use it unquoted. Why not just quote your strings properly?

I don't remember any such thing as unquoted strings, and I started using SQL Server with SQL Server 7. This code was always bad and there's no reason to ask why this fails. There's no proof that this worked in 2012 either. BTW both SQL Server 2012 and 2014 are out of support - 2014 reaches the end of even extended support in July 2024

Yep, MERGE was also reserved in SQL Server 2012 (and in 2008)

MERGE was introduced in MS SQL 2008 ,  the main point is why a keyword is working without single quotes in MSSQL 2012 but not in MSSQL 2014 since both versions came after the introduction of MERGE.

What compatibility level is the database set to on the 2012 instance? Is it 90, by any chance? What about the database on 2014?

@SagarShirke this isn't about merge, it's about the claim that unquoted strings ever worked. Even if there was such a quirk ages ago, eg to maintain compatibility with Sybase,  it was fixed. No supported version allows this any more. Fix the code

@PanagiotisKanavos yes they do. db<>fiddle It's also specifically documented that it's allowed: "If you pass a single word that does not begin with @ and that's not enclosed in quotation marks - for example, if you forget @ on a parameter name - the word is treated as an nvarchar string, in spite of the missing quotation marks." That doesn't, however, mean you should and I agree that the syntax is a bad choice.

@ThomA 1) that contradicts the OP's claim and 2) I'll try very hard to forget I ever saw this

@ThomA , you are spot on. Its compatibility level is 90.  You can post it as  answer.

It doesn't, @PanagiotisKanavos, reserved keywords are still reserved keywords.

The MERGE operator was added to SQL Server in 2008 and, at the same point, MERGE was made a Reserved Keyword. As a result when using an unquoted literal with the value MERGE it will be seen as the start of the MERGE operator and that is not allowed when using EXEC.
Although it was added in 2008 (and you are using 2012), if you are using an old compatibility level (90 or lower) then the keyword may not be treated as one, as it wasn't a reserved keyword in SQL Server 2005. This would explain why you are getting different behaviour in SQL Server 2012 and 2014, as 2012 did support compatibility 90, where as 2014 did not: Support matrix. If your database was at level 90 and restored on a 2014 instance, its compatibility level would have been raised.
Of course, in reality, you really should not be using compatibility 90 anymore (again, that's SQL Server 2005!), or even SQL Server 2012 (that reached end of life 2 years ago), and even 2014 reaches end of life in less than a month. Also, although the syntax EXEC <ProcName> (@ParameterName = ) <Literal> is allowed, you really shouldn't be using it for strings; use a string literal. 'merge' is the syntax you should be using. This avoids the problem above, as well as if you were to have other reserved keywords, or if you have a string that needs to be delimited (starts with a digit, has non-alphanumerical characters, etc).
